# iphone app shows white screen when first launched, but okay when entered again

Tags: iphone, ios

the iphone app I am writing shows white screen when first launched, but become okay when entered again.
when I press home button of iphone, then enter the app again, it displays correctly.
(actually when I have just pressed the button and when seeing the app goes from foreground to background, I saw the correct app root display)
This problem also happen when I haven't enter the app for a certain period of time.
Anybody has ever encountered this problem?
How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: What is your question ? Can you please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I'd say that in your app delegate, the code you want in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is in `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Answer (score 2):

you may not be setting the rootViewController in `applicationDidFinishWithOptions:` but instead setting them in `applicationWillEnterForeground`

could you post your code for those two functions so we can see

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't have described my problem better myself, so you can imagine my frustration at the answer not being here yet. To that end I'll add my solution:

Given that you're doing the right stuff in your applicationDidFinishWithOptions: method and not in applicationWillEnterForeground, something along the lines of: 
    navcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
    [window addSubview:nc.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

make sure to double check the following:

1. Your delegate is hooked up to the appropriate window in your MainWindow.xib
2. You've ticked the "visible at launch" box in interface builder for the window.
3. In your Target Info (or info.plist) make sure "Main nib file base name" is "MainWindow"
4. This is the bit that caught me out - if you have two windows in your mainwindow nib (I had a second that I use later to display a full screen image) make sure that you hide it, I set it to hidden in interface builder and unhide when you need it, I also unchecked the "visible at launch" box for good measure.
   From a spot of googling I found that if you're getting a white screen you'll likely be getting an "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error, meaning the delegate can't find a nib to load, however if you're getting a black screen  and nothing in the debugger then it is loading some nib just not necessarily the one or the part of one you're expecting. Mine was loading the blank window over the one that I wanted (the one with the correct nib in it), (I think).

Happy bug fixing!